# sortBy in React?

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I fetch the data from a server and some items have a specific attribute others don't. I need to sort data according to **this specific attribute** and I am using **sortBy** package but of course it doesn't work properly because when it tries to sort data  and doesn't find the attribute, it is broken.

```
myItems.sort(sortBy('specificAttr'))
```

Basically, what I did (think of inside of a loop):

```
 if(!myItems.specificAttr) {myItems.speficificAttr = 0);
```

I know it doesn't make sense at all, but I don't know what I can do.

Do you have any advice with code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using [lodash's `sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sortBy)

Lodash handles this case out of the box. If it can't find the attribute, it gets pushed to the end of the sorted array.

```js
var users = [
  { 'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 }
];
 
_.sortBy(users, [(o) => { return o.user; }]);
// => objects for barney, barney, fred, and no-name in that order

_.sortBy(users, ['user']);
// => objects for barney, barney, fred, and no-name in that order
```

If you're using some other library's `sortBy`, check the documentation to see if there's an optional second argument that would allow you to customize the attribute getter function.

### Rolling your own

If you're implementing your own sorting algorithm, simply do a check like `if myItem.specificAttr` to check if the attribute exists while you're doing the actual sorting (rather than prior sorting, as you described in your example).